# What schools are there that can make a good weaponsmith/armorsmith?

Tags: character-creation, crafting, l5r-4e

What schools are there that can make a good weaponsmith/armorsmith? In past editions there were specific weapon/armorsmith classes.

So far I have only found [the Shiba Artisan](http://lasthaiku.wikidot.com/scphoenix#toc5) and the [Kakita Artisan](http://lasthaiku.wikidot.com/sccrane#toc7) but since Weaponsmith and Armorsmith are actually Craft skills and not Artisan skills, they aren't much benefit without a little GM hand-waving.

Are there any that I've overlooked? Alternatively, is there any other school that provides proper bonuses to make a good armorsmith or weaponsmith?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Kaiu Engineer](http://lasthaiku.wikidot.com/sccrab#toc5): *(Crab Clan School)*, --Great Clans p39,
- [Kitsune Artisan](http://lasthaiku.wikidot.com/scmantis#toc15): *(Path, replaces Kitsune Shugenja 2)* --Strongholds of the Empire p25
- [Shiba Armorsmiths](http://lasthaiku.wikidot.com/scphoenix#toc19): *(Path, replaces Shiba Bushi 2)* --Book of Earth p193
- [Tamori Weaponsmiths](http://lasthaiku.wikidot.com/scdragon#toc21): *(Path, replaces Tamori Shugenja 2)* --Book of Earth p195
- [Tsi Smith](http://lasthaiku.wikidot.com/scminor#toc11): *(Oriole Clan School)* --L5R Core p222
- [Water Hammer Smith](http://lasthaiku.wikidot.com/scdragon#toc23): *(Path, replaces any Dragon School at Rank 2)* --Strongholds of the Empire p108

I didn't include the Artisan schools that had no Craft bonus inherent to the school.

Comment: Wow! Such an extensive list, thank you! And here I was wondering if there was any at all! *(I took the liberty of adding links for completeness :) )* I feel tempted to accept your answer but I will wait a bit out of courtesy ^^

Answer (score 2):

I might mix up editions and can't check at the moment but I think both the [Kaiu Engineer](http://l5r.wikia.com/wiki/Kaiu_Engineer) and the [Tsi Smith](http://l5r.wikia.com/wiki/Tsi_Blacksmith) are 4th edition schools that have techniques that make them better weapon and/or armorsmiths

I can't access the lasthaiku page from where I am at the moment but I think the Kaiu engineer should be found [here](http://lasthaiku.wikidot.com/sccrab) and the Tsi smith unter minor clan schools.

Comment: ..you're right on both! :D  I totally overlooked the Kaiu because I remembered them being all about siege weapons from 3rd edition. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I find this site very useful: http://pixel-breath.com/imperial-registry-index-of-all-schools-in-l5r-4e/